# How to determine when a user's account will be locked in HP-UX

Tags: unix, hp-ux

I'm trying to figure out how to determine when user accounts on an HP-UX server will be locked.  I would need this for every user on the server.

On other kinds of UNIX, this kind of this is typically found in the /etc/shadow file as the 8th field in each row (# of days since the 1/1/1970 when the account will be disabled).

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been reading, this will do it:

```
/usr/lbin/getprpw -r -m acctexp <username>
```

http://www.hpuxtips.es/?q=node/157

http://fixunix.com/security/74478-scripts-needed-trusted-hp-ux-system.html

Answer (score 0):

It is the same on HP-UX, the 8th field in /etc/shadow tells you:

(from `man shadow` on HP-UX 11.31)

```
expiration     The absolute number of days since Jan 1, 1970
               after which the account is no longer valid.  A
               value of zero in this field indicates that the
               account is locked.
```

Also, it should be noted that if an account is locked due to too many authentication attemps, you won't see that in /etc/shadow. You can find out the failed logins count of an account with

```
userdbget -u username auth_failures
```

and test if it is >= than the value of AUTH_MAXTRIES defined in /etc/default/security.

Comment: It looks like in some cases, the /etc/shadow file won't be there: http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1298402971526+28353475&threadId=1237808

Comment: If you are on a trusted system, it is not there and replaced (never used it so I don't really know). If not, I strongly suggest, for security reasons, you convert your /etc/passwd with the command pwconv which will create the /etc/shadow file.